# Let's get -- Is this a grammatical sentence?

Tags: idioms

Is this a grammatical sentence?  Is it idiomatic for "Let's go?"

Comment: It's been used for at least a hundred years, it's understood by the vast majority of native (US) English speakers.  How else would you describe "grammatical"?

Answer (score 5):

It's colloquial, and might often be spelled, "Let's git," to reflect the pronunciation. It would be short for "Let's get going" or, as you suggest, "Let's go."

It isn't grammatical in and of itself because "to get" requires an object.

Comment: *Git* can also be used in the sense of *scram* (to depart in a hurry; to flee), so "Let's git" would have a connotation of immediate, rapid departure.

Comment: I'm not sure you necessarily have to postulate *any* particular word or phrase elided after *"Let's git!"*. Does plain *"Go!"* have to be seen as short for *"Go away [from me]!"*, for example? But personally I usually imagine this one as being *"Let's **git/get** the hell outta here!"*.

Answer (score 1):

To "get" in English *can* be used to mean "to go", but usually in the sense that someone would shout "get!" to you-- "get" being short for "get lost".

So with that in mind, "let's get" could be interpreted as "let's get lost" which in turn could mean "let's go".  But, it's definitely a slang sentence and not a complete one, and I've never seen the phrase used in that sense.  Where did you encounter it?

Comment: Might "Get!" stand for "Get going!" as JAM suggests?

Comment: i am scoring neurospsychological testing.

Comment: Wow, ok.  Yes, I think JAM is also right.